# Ayuda sumando la siguiente consulta (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle-11g

Tengo el siguiente select el cual necesito sumar la cantidad cuando se repite el mismo articulo en el mismo contenedor y lote.

```
SELECT 
LOTE,FECHA_CADUCIDAD,CANTIDAD,CODIGO_CONTENEDOR,ARTICULO,NUMERO_PEDIDO
FROM XXOSI.XXOSI_OMBULLN_SIS_IN_T 
WHERE NUMERO_PEDIDO = 'I-142585778531' 
AND ARTICULO = '43758' 
AND CODIGO_CONTENEDOR = '4'
ORDER BY FECHA_CADUCIDAD;
```

Si corro esta query me trae la siguiente información:

[image: SUM]

Como se puede apreciar tengo un mismo numero de `articulo`.
un mismo `lote`
un mismo `contenedor`
un mismo `numero de pedido`

Lo que necesito es poder sumar la cantidad y que se muestre un solo registro de articulo con la cantidades sumadas, ademas de que si el Lote es diferente se abra la query y no se sume  la cantidad si no que me muestre todos los registros de articulo en un mismo contenedor para un numero de pedido pero con un lote diferente.

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con una subquery dentro de tu **SELECT** así:

```
SELECT a*
(select 
   sum(CANTIDAD) 
     from XXOSI.XXOSI_OMBULLN_SIS_IN_T 
       where LOTE = a.LOTE 
       and ARTICULO = a.ARTICULO 
       and CODIGO_CONTENEDOR = a.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR) as CANT_TOTAL

   FROM XXOSI.XXOSI_OMBULLN_SIS_IN_T a
        WHERE a.NUMERO_PEDIDO = 'I-142585778531' 
           AND a.ARTICULO = '43758' 
           AND a.CODIGO_CONTENEDOR = '4'
             ORDER BY a.FECHA_CADUCIDAD;
```

Espero te sirva.